# How to manually install a cpp library

Tags: path, libraries, c++, opengl

I want to install the opengl sdk http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/pg_build.html . I successfully built it but it has no install script.

I am wondering where I have to put them in order for eclipse to find them with `-lname`.

It seems that I can install header only libraries by just putting them in `/usr/include`. But I have no idea where I have to put `name.a` files.

I installed GLFW with pacman. I can find it in `/usr/include/GL/glfw.h` but I have no idea where the real library is located.

I hope you can clear things up.

Comment: Try looking at [these instructions](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/pg_use.html) for the how-to use.

Answer (score 0):

The `lib` folders are what hold the actual binary libraries for the compiler to link to or include in the executable if it is statically linked.

Where you have  `-lname` you can just use the actual location of the `.a`/`.so` files.

This only works if the `.so` file stays there. That is if you dynamically link to the `.so` file. If you add the `-static` option than it will pull in the binary data from the .a file into your executable file when it compiles it. Then it does not matter if you delete the `.a`/`.so` files.

Here's [a good reference for what dynamic libraries and static libraries](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) are and how to create them with `gcc`. Reading it will help you a lot.